# .Net Maui Align Shell Tabs

Tags: tabs, alignment, maui

I have a .Net Maui project that is using Shell Tabs. The tabs at the bottom of the app align perfectly filling in all the space evenly. The tabs that are inserted on a content page are aligning to the left and not filling in all the space.

As you can see the tabs at the bottom are aligned the way I want filling in all available space. The tabs labeled 11/7, 11/8, 11/9 & 11/10 are aligning to the left. What I want is for them to align the same as the tabs at the bottom filling in all available space and being even width.

[image]

Here is the code block for the TabBar in the Shell.

```
 <TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Dashboard">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.House}"
                                 Color="Black"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Sessions" >
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS" 
                                 Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.ChalkboardUser}"
                                 Color="Black"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Title="11/7" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SessionsDay1}" Route="SessionsDay1"/>
        <ShellContent Title="11/8" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SessionsDay2}" Route="SessionsDay2"/>
        <ShellContent Title="11/9" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SessionsDay3}" Route="SessionsDay3"/>
        <ShellContent Title="11/10" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SessionsDay4}" Route="SessionsDay4"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Schedule">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS" 
                                 Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarDays}"
                                 Color="Black"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Schedule}" Route="Schedule"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Speakers" FlyoutItemIsVisible="False">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS" 
                                 Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Users}"
                                 Color="Black"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Speakers}" Route="Speakers"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Menu">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS" 
                                 Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Bars}"
                                 Color="Black"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Menu}" Route="Menu"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To align the `width` of Maui Shell Tabs evenly, you can use the [Using Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) to achieve it.

Below are the detailed steps:

1. Create the platform-specific implementation file `CustomShellRenderer.cs` under `Platform/Android`:

```
using AndroidApp = Android.App.Application;

namespace MauiAppShell.Platforms.Android
{
    public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// CustomShellRenderer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            
        }

        protected override IShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(ShellSection shellSection)
        {
            return new MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(this);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// CustomShellItemRenderer  
    /// </summary>  
    public class MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker : ShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker
    {
        public MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
        {
        }
        public override void SetAppearance(TabLayout tabLayout, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(tabLayout, appearance);
            var displayWidth = (int)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
            {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);
                if (tab.CustomView == null)
                {
                    TextView textview = new TextView(AndroidApp.Context)
                    {
                        Text = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i).Text,
                        TextSize = 20,
                        Typeface = Typeface.DefaultBold,
                        Gravity = GravityFlags.Center
                    };
                    textview.SetWidth(displayWidth / 5);
                    tab.SetCustomView(textview);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally, register our handlers like below in the `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => { 
#if ANDROID
         
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell),typeof(CustomShellRenderer));
#endif
})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: So Simple and worked like a charm. Thank you, you saved me hours of frustration.

Comment: Very nice answer. Perhaps `displayWidth / 5` could be changed to `displayWidth / tabLayout.TabCount`?

Comment: Good catch, however, it looks like it'll only render 3 tabs if changed to `displayWidth / tabLayout.TabCount`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case alignment didn't work with Alexandar's answer. Three tabs were wider than the screen. I solved it by a small adjustment:

Replaced these lines:

```cs
public override void SetAppearance(TabLayout tabLayout, ShellAppearance appearance)
{
    base.SetAppearance(tabLayout, appearance);
    var displayWidth = (int)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
    {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);
        if (tab.CustomView == null)
        {
            TextView textview = new TextView(AndroidApp.Context)
            {
                Text = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i).Text,
                TextSize = 20,
                Typeface = Typeface.DefaultBold,
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Center
            };
            textview.SetWidth(displayWidth / 5);
            tab.SetCustomView(textview);
        }
    }
}
```

By these:

```cs
public override void SetAppearance(TabLayout tabLayout, ShellAppearance appearance)
{
    base.SetAppearance(tabLayout, appearance);

    tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeFixed;
    tabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;
}
```

[image]